# why is one style sheet overriding the other

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

im new to webdesigning but basicaly i have two stylesheet one for mobile and one for tablet size which i made in dreamweaver, the problem that im having is that, the tablets css rules are overiding the mobile stylesheets rules. i know that order matters for when im listing them, but why doesnt it switch from one style sheet to the other depending on the screen size.

in my index page I have it implemented like this.

```
<!-- Mobile -->
<link href="css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-   width:800px)" />
<!-- Tablet -->
<link href="css/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:801px;)" />
```

THESE ARE THE RULES I HAVE IN MY TWO DIFFERENT stylesheets

```
▼
```

THIS IS MY MOBILE:

```
    article{
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        max-width: 400px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        padding: 5px 10px 8px 15px;
    }   

    img{
        max-width:100%;
    }

    #desktop_img{
        float:left;

        padding:0;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #welcome{
        float:left;
        max-width:90%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    #welcome{
        text-align:center;
    }

    #hobbies{
        max-width:90%;
        float:left;
        margin-bottom: 5.0em;
    }

    #hobbies h1 {
        text-align:center;
    }
```

AND THIS IS MY TABLET:

```
    article{
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid white;
        max-width: 400px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
        font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        padding: 5px 10px 8px 15px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    img{
        max-width:100%;
    }

    #desktop_img{
        float:left;
        padding-left:20%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #welcome{
        float:left;
        max-width:100%;
        padding-left:20%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    #welcome{
        text-align:center;
    }

    #hobbies{
        float:left;
        max-width:100%;
        margin-bottomg: 5.0em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-left:20%;
    }

    #hobbies h1 {
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: try to putt min-width first and remove the semicolon

Comment: try using javascript to detect the user agent, then store a cookie for their user agent. based on the cookie, you could load a stylesheet in asynchronously. alternatively, you could use media queries instead of separate stylesheets, and avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: tried doing it as @media only screen 
and (max-width : 800px) {
it still doesnt work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is picky, try

Change

```
media="only screen and (max-   width:800px)"
media="only screen and (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:801px;)"
```

To

```
media="only screen and (max-width: 800px)"
media="only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 801px)"
```

If all else fails, check Dev Tools to spot check what is being applied. If the browser doesn't know what you are talking about, it silently fails.

Comment: the space between max-    width was a typo when posting it here, but thanks i removed the semicolon at the end of 801, still no progress =[

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon at the end after "min-width:801px;" is causing your problems. Removing it should fix your problem.

```
<link href="css/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:801px)" />
```

Working example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/okteL
(Change viewport size to see body change colour)

Also you may want to look at not using exclusive media queries in the way you have. It leads to a lot of duplicate code which will be difficult to maintain (and slower to load). For example, currently if you wanted to change the background colour of article you would have to change it in 2 places even though it should be the same at any width.

I would advise deciding on whether you want to design for mobile or desktop first and then use media queries to *override* only the code you want changing for other screen sizes.

More here:
http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

Comment: i did that but it didnt fix the issue.

Comment: Have you checked out the working example? Can you post a link to some live code which shows the problem?